# Get "An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required" for event_loop.run_until_complete() method

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a code that runs in a loop infinetely written in Python3.6. Inside the loop I get data through web3.py. I want to process that data asynchronously. I used asyncio. Here is my code:

```
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(cfg.eth_node_url))
web3_pending_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
taskLock = Lock()
tasks = []

def main():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=start_event_loop)
    thread.start()

    while True:
       process_pending_trx(web3, web3_pending_filter)
       time.sleep(0.001)           


def start_event_loop():
    while True:
        buf = []
        with taskLock:
            for task in tasks:
                buf.append(task)
            tasks = []

        if len(buf) > 0:
            event_loop.run_until_complete(buf)

        time.sleep(0.0001)


def process_pending_trx(web3, web3_filter):
    print('Scanning for new pending transactions...')

    transaction_list = web3.eth.getFilterChanges(web3_filter.filter_id)
    print(len(transaction_list))

    for trx_hash in transaction_list:
        with taskLock:
            tasks.append(process_pending_transaction(web3, trx_hash))


async def process_pending_transaction(web3, trx_hash):
    print(trx_hash)
    trx = web3.eth.getTransaction(trx_hash)  
    ...
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

In **start_event_loop** method for line

> event_loop.run_until_complete(buf)
>   I got error: "An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required"

What might be a reason of this error? Or how can I asynchronously run **process_pending_transaction** method? Maybe there are some other ways.

Comment: You can’t just pass a list to `run_until_complete`. You need to give it something awaitable. Take a look at [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html).

Comment: Perhaps this should be an answer?